# Wso2 gadget generation error

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

good day everyone. I have downloaded the Wso2 DAS server for reporting purposes to make various dashboards. i successfully added my Oracle database to the datasources and the connection is healthy! however when i make an attempt to generate a gadget using the relational DB source its gives me the following error (Error! in database configuration). ive checked my DB url and its perfect , i have literally searched everything on google. i even tried using a batch data source but i fall flat on that attempt as well. please help me! am i missing a crucial step before adding a gadget or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gadget generation in DAS 3.1.0 was not supported for oracle database. So this error is normal. All the issues with oracle and other major databases like DB2, PostgreSQL, MSSQL was fixed with this [pull request](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-dashboards/pull/471/files). Since a release does not happen after this change, you can build a DAS pack locally and check.
Or you can do the following

1. Get the changed files from pull request.
2. Copy and replace these changed files with files in `<DAS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/extensions/providers/rdbms`
3. Now check gadget creation.

Comment: ok i got the files needed. so how do i configure these files to my wso2 environment? i am not too techically versed so pls forgive my ignorance

Comment: @kaylinMorgan: I have added more details to the answer.

Comment: thanks alot, the connection is working and i am able to create my gadgets to a certain point. in the beginning could i see all my options for various graphs and charts (e.g. x axis, y axis, etc) but now its limiting my options to just inserting the gadget name and type. on the back end the error that appears is : TypeError: Cannot read property "error" from undefined (/portal/controllers/apis/createGadget.jag#167) .      is there a line i should add ?

Comment: You are saying, you can only type gadget name and type and if you fill other field also, you will get this backend error?

Comment: the only options available for me is to fill in the gadget name and gadget type.... the rest of the options (x-axis, y-axis, etc) are not visible. And then i get this error backend: TypeError: Cannot read property "error" from undefined (/portal/controllers/apis/createGadget.jag#167)

Comment: The configured limitof 1,000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph.This can be avoided by adding stop points with @IgnoreSizeOf annotations. Since the CacheManger or Cache <sizeOfPolicy> elements maxDepthExceededBehavior is set to "abort", the sizing operation has stopped and the reported cache size is not accurate. If performance degradation is NOT an issue at the configured limit, raise the limit value using the CacheManager or Cache<sizeOfPolicy> elements maxDepth attribute. For more information, see the Ehcache configuration documentation.

Comment: the above is the error i get in the bakend if i go ahead and fill in the gadget name and type and press 'preview'.